# try to build bsp recipe but an error occured required build target 'sysdig-driver'

Tags: yocto

i have this msg error while trying to build sysdig-driver

```
    ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'libb64' (but /home/stm/meta-st-stm32mp/recipes-bsp/drivers/sysdig-driver_git.bb DEPENDS on or otherwise requires it). Close matches:
      libqb
    ERROR: Required build target 'sysdig-driver' has no buildable providers.
    Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['sysdig-driver', 'libb64']
```

i didnt set the distro yet